# Python pdb skip/delete line

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

When I want to debug a Python code, I always add the following line to the places for breakpoint

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Sometimes it is placed inside a `for` loop. And after I inspect certain variables, I want to skip/delete this line so that it can continue running. Is there is a way to do that? Thank you~!

Comment: It seems you cannot ignore a hard-coded break point. Instead you can use `python -m pdb script.py` to run your script in debug mode and use `unt(il) [lineno]` to where you want. Or you can set a break point by `b(reak) [([filename:]lineno | function) [, condition]]`

Comment: The easy way to do this is to just do the `set_trace()` once, at the start of the program, then you can add a breakpoint from inside the debugger, as Sraw explains, which you can disable and enable (or put a condition on). The hard way is to write your condition into your code: `if breakhere: pdb.set_trace()`, with a global `breakhere=True`. Then you can skip it by just setting `breakhere=False`.